# use variable in page and use this variable in another page

Tags: php, mysql

I need help how i can use variable in page and use this variable in another page.

Like in register.php

```
$query=mysql_query( " INSERT INTO user (firstname,lastname,username,email,password,country)
                                VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$username','$email','$password','$country') ") or die(mysql_error() );

 }
$a=1;

   if(isset($query) && $captcha == $kemet )


    header("Location: check_register.php");
```

and in check_register.php

```
 if($a=1){ echo "hello";}
```

For that i want to use variable `$a` in check_register When all the conditions finished in register  and  go to check_register

I tried

```
$query=mysql_query( " INSERT INTO user  
                        (firstname,lastname,username,
                        email,password,country) 
            VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$username',
                    '$email','$password','‌​$country') ") 
    or die(mysql_error() ); 
} 
$a=1; 
if(isset($query) && $captcha == $kemet ) 
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username; 
    header("Location: login_done.php");
```

and in check_register

```
if($_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;) {
    echo "hello ";
}
```

Comment: you can add value of variable in a session

Comment: yeah i did it but nothing

Comment: ...so post what you tried.

Comment: too many unknowns also

Comment: LIKE   $query=mysql_query( " INSERT INTO user (firstname,lastname,username,email,password,country)
                                    VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$username','$email','$password','$country') ") or die(mysql_error() );

 }
$a=1;

   if(isset($query) && $captcha == $kemet )
                                        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;


    header("Location: login_done.php"); and in check_register if($_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;) {echo "hello ";}

Comment: with this `if($_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;)` you assign that value,
change it for this `if($_SESSION['login_user'] ==$username)`

Comment: @eslamalshbah Nobody can read code in a comment, in future edit your question to add additional information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to use query string ..

Like this : `header("Location: check_register.php?result=1");`

And in check_register.php you need to get that with `$a = $_GET['result']` or 
`$a = $_REQUEST['result']`